# jmeter with BI4 .2 SP6

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded script through Blaze meter and tried executing thru jmeter after adding com.sun.faces and bttoken. I have tried adding sEntry but unfortunately I didn't find the key.

Issue: It is not performing refresh report activity because I was monitoring in the backed sessions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [BI4 Web Intelligence Performance Test with JMeter](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-45507) article it should be `strEntry` and the relevant [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration would be something like

[image]

Actually you can use another approach to recording JMeter tests which can export recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic data, it might help you to come up with the properly [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) version of the load test with the minimal efforts. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/) article for more details.

If you need further help on manual correlation consider including previous sampler response and the next request details into your question